# Setup amazon aurora as replica to mariadb master

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, aws-aurora, aurora

I am trying to setup replication between MariaDB 10.4.17 and Aurora 5.7.12 MySQL, with Mariadb as master and aurora as replica.
I am following this [aws article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html)

I noted the file name and position

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| binlog.000169 |  1387829 |              |                  |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

I created mysql dump from mariadb and loaded that into aurora.
after which I created a replication user on the master instance like this

`CREATE USER 'replication_aurora'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'repl_pass';`

`GRANT REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication_aurora'@'%';`

and called the procedure on Aurora

```
CALL mysql.rds_set_external_master ('ip of master', 3306,
    'replication_aurora', '<password>', 'binlog.000169', 1387829, 0);
```

more about the above procedure [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html)
then i called this procedure

```
CALL mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

This was supposed to start replication but I am getting this when i run
`SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: master_ip
                  Master_User: replication_aurora
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: binlog.000169
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1387829
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: binlog.000169
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_sysinfo,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_history
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1387829
              Relay_Log_Space: 2754
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1593
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because a fatal error is encountered when it tries to get the value of SERVER_UUID variable from master.
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 210424 15:42:38
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

I am thinking error could be while creating the user I created `'replication_aurora'@'%'` instead of creating `'replication_aurora'@'replica ip'` is this the issue?

I am unable to check because the connection endpoint aurora gives is more than 60characters long so i cannot create a user with that endpoint on my mariadb master.

Question.

1. is not giving replica ip in user is the issue?
2. is compatibility the issue?
3. should i also create the same user on replica?

I am sort of at a dead end here please help any article or video would be helpful

Comment: @danblack yes, seems like mariadb 10.4 is incompatible with mysql 5.7, i am new to this, if you don't mind me asking do you think downgrading to 5.6 would work?

Comment: Possibly, though be very careful. In replication topological the slave/replica should have the superset of features, therefore it should be a greater major version than the master. Otherwise there's the possibility that the master will give a the slave a message it cannot understand. Probably take a look at again at your initial goal, what do you want to acheive with this replication?

Comment: My company is trying to move on from Mariadb to aurora but want to first keep aurora as a replica and see if all the features are working and are compatible and then we'd probably move on to the opposite architecture as having a mariadb replica and an aurora master.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to use [maxscale mirror](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-mirror/) or some AWS way of forking the web traffic between a Aurora instance and a RDS for MariaDB instance. Maybe [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) can help create an initial replica. Sorry, out of ideas. What the biggest driver for moving?

Comment: Driver for moving is, it is quiet handful to manage mariadb instance, and if we can put that work on a service for a bit of money  that's acceptable.